# using a c++ class in another class using v8?

Tags: c++, v8

I defined a c++ class name "FirstClass.cc", and in another c++ class name "SecondClass.cc" that is using namespace v8 I included an object from the first class like this:

```
 #include <FirstClass.hh>
    using namespace v8;

    static Handle<Value> function_A(const Arguments& arguments){
       Local<Object> args = Local<Object>::Cast(arguments[0]);
       HandleScope scope;
       FirstClass newObj;
       return scope.Close(String::New("OK"));
    }
```

but I got this error:
node: symbol lookup error: /path/to/build/Release/SecondClass.node: undefined symbol: _ZN6SP
I want to know how should I define an object from FirstClass? shall I wrapp the FirstClass in v8?

Comment: Should this be a static member function of `SecondClass`? In that case it should be ``static Handle<Value> SecondClass::function_A(const Arguments& arguments){...`

Comment: What is the purpose of this function ? You create a `FirstClass` object, but you don't seem to use it after...

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: yeah I want to use it later, this code is just for some illustration.

Comment: @Hulk: this function has problem with defining "newObj", although I have included the header file of "FirstClass",how should I define a new object from "FirstClass" ?

Comment: @user2293743 why do you think that the problem is in this line?